# Looking for the equivalent of dictcursor in flaskext.mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I've written a Python Flask app, and initially used MySQLdb to access MySQL. Later I've switched to flaskext.mysql for the same purposes, but now when I use this module I cannot see how to get a dictionary structured cursor.

When I using the MySQLdb module I was using the following line to open a dictionary based cursor -

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('localhost','root','root','transport')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with flaskext.mysql, my currect code looks like this -

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
```

What should I feed the cursor object in order to get the same type of cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql.get_db()`](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/master/flaskext/mysql.py#L58) would result into your "connection" object, you can do:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

cur = mysql.get_db().cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Or, you can also set the default `cursorclass` when initializing the extension:

```
mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but this actually explains what I've already achieved. I was wondering how to do the same as you described using the flaskext.mysql module, and where can I find more documentation about it (right now all I can find is this page - https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If I supply mdb.cursors.dictcursor it doesn't work, naturally, as the flaskext doesn't recognize the cursor type.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but since it opened my eyes to the fact I don't have to use flaskext and better off with mysqldb I think its good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think @alecxe was hinting at this in his last code block, but you can use 
a DictCursor with the Flask extension as follows:

As well as the Flask MySQL extension you need the DictCursor

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
```

Then simply add the parameter `cursorclass=DictCursor` when creating the MySQL object:

```
mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=DictCursor)
```

I'm using this in my own Flask app and it seems to be working as expected

*Note: I discovered this solution lurking in a comment in the issue queue in the Github repo for the project [here](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues/9).  I do wish the library documentation was more than a few lines long.*