# TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary' using flaskext.mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm using flask framework and MySQL database connector.

I did the below:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
## app.config database configuration code
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor();
cursor.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = (%s)', (username,)
    )
user = cursor.fetchone()
```

I can access the user columns using index like `user[8]` (which I need to execute the query once and check the column number), but when I try to specify

```
conn = mysql.connect(dictionary=True)
```

I get the error

> 'TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary''

Is there a way to get the results of the query in dictionary format when using flask-MySQL?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980044/looking-for-the-equivalent-of-dictcursor-in-flaskext-mysql

Comment: Great!! that worked. I tried both the answers and second one worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388992/3129414

**Existing code modification:**

- use `DictCursor` in `MySQL` initialization
- remove `dictionary=True` from cursor
- use `json` package to convert dictionary items to json format

`app.py`:

```
import json
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'practice_db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=DictCursor)
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def home():
    email_address = 'dummy@example.com'
    cursor = conn.cursor();
    cursor.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email = (%s)', (email_address,)
        )
    users = cursor.fetchall()
    return json.dumps(users)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Screenshot:

[image: dictionary output using flaskext]

Comment: @Nanditha, sounds great! :) Please give an upvote so that future readers will find this answer useful.

Comment: I've given an upvote, but I'm not sure if it would be visible to everyone as my reputation points are not sufficient.

Comment: You are right. According to help link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you need just a few points more. Anyway, hope your journey with Stackoverflow will be cheerful. :)