# how can i get sum of selected checkbox and save selected item in database mysql

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, checkbox

am trying to create a web page for the menu in a restaurant that contains menu (name and price of food). What I want is in the front end when user select menu by clicking the checkbox, he gets the total of price on the webpage. Also, to be able to extract the names of the menu he selects and saves them on MySQL database using python flask.

What I have done is to create a two list from database one is for names of food and the other one is of the prices but what I get is this.

[image: the result i get]

```py
def ef menu1():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT name FROM menu ''')
    name = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('''SELECT price FROM menu ''')
    price = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('''SELECT MAX(num) FROM menu''')
    maxi=cur.fetchone()
    maxid = int(maxi[0])

    return render_template('test4.html',name = name,price=price , maxid=maxid)
```

```html
<div class= "row" style="background-image: url('{{url_for('static',filename='images/bg-01.jpg')}}');"><!-- -->     
    <div class= "col-lg-6">
        <br>
        <p>
            <strong>Food</strong> 
            <br />
            {% for n in range(maxid) %}
            <br />
            <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" name="activity['food']['breakfast']" value="{{price[n]}}"> The Menu {{name[n]}} is {{price[n]}} Tshs
            <br/> 
            {% endfor %}
        </p> 
        <p>
            <strong>Amount (US$)</strong>: 
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```py
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/jquery-3.4.1.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {        
            $(".my-activity").click(function(event) {
                var total = 0;
                $(".my-activity:checked").each(function() {
                    total += parseInt($(this).val());
                });
                if (total == 0) {
                    $('#amount').val('');
                } else {                
                    $('#amount').val(total);
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding total without ```parseInt```

Comment: @shihab if i use `int` without `parseInt` i have to add the button to calculate sum. by the way i have tried but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

HTML and jQuery were perfect and you were rendering invalid value filed for checkbox.

So i simplified your Python code.

```
def ef_menu1():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT name,price FROM menu')
    name = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()    
    return render_template('test4.html', name=name)
```

Update your flask template part to the following code

```
{% for n in name %}
<br />
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" name="activity['food']['breakfast']" value="{{n[1]}}"> The Menu {{n[0]}} is {{n[1]}} Tshs
<br/> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: am using flask_mysqldb and i run the code i found an error in this line of code" cur = mysql.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)" the error is TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'

Comment: Edited code try this..If not You can fix previous issue with the following links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368579/typeerror-cursor-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-dictionary-using-flaske?noredirect=1&lq=1    OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980044/looking-for-the-equivalent-of-dictcursor-in-flaskext-mysql/41388992#41388992